# PHPDocumentor - what's wrong with my DocBlock?

Tags: php, phpdoc, docblocks

I'm putting in some comments in some legacy code, and I've run across a small issue with PHPDocumentor.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Constructs the Widget object
 * 
 * Basic constructor for the widget object.
 * Another line of pointless explanation, badly worded.
 *
 * @param  string   $id    The ID of the widget
 * @param  int      $size  The Size of the widget
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function __construct($id, $size) {
    if (!is_string($id) || !is_integer($size)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$id must be a string, $size an integer');
    }
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->size = $size;
}
```

I run PHPDocumentor from the command-line, and get a lovely folder full of documentation.

The documentation looks fine, but I get PHPDocumentor compilation errors along the lines of:

```
Argument $id is missing from the Docblock of __construct
```

Is it just PHPDocumenator whining unnecessarily, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that it is pointing to that file?

Comment: Yep! The documentation itself looks complete, but it's still throwing errors in the errors.html file.

Comment: Can it be that any letter is entered in another non-ASCII keyboard layout?

Comment: __construct doesn't return so shoudn't have @return void there. Just a nitpick :)

Comment: Good catch. Apols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with phpDocumentor version 2.8.1. It seems it's a bug in this version:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1476)

I used [version 2.7.0](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/tree/v2.7.0) and it's fine now.

Comment: Ehsan's link takes you to the explanation of unpatched issue, that can be fixed by building , and patching from the GitHub source. Hopefully it will be fixed in 3.0.